# Simple Unit Testing NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Hi I am pretty new to NodeJs and I am trying to write my first tests.

I am kind of stuck with the setup, so I was hoping for some help.

I wrote these two functions:

```
app.js:

var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.get('/a_nice_jsonp',cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next){
  var result = parseCookies(req);
  res.jsonp(result);
});

app.get('',function(req,res,next){
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end()
});
```

I do not export it as module as it is my only file.

I assume it's pretty easy to write the tests for that. I started with something like this:

```
app-test.js:

var expect = require('expect.js');
var express = require('express');
var expressApp = express();

describe('app js test', function() {
  describe('GET /', function() {
    it('should respond to GET with empty path', function () {
      expressApp.get('', function(req, res, body){
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
      });
    })
  });
});
```

I suppose it really reads like a simple task, but I seem to fail over the setup of the test and how to do it.

Can anyone help me out here?

EDIT: The above test runs fine. However, I have difficulties to test e.g. `.end()` as well as the `result` in the `jsonp request`. I simple do not know how to do it?!

Comment: Is there any error message? how did you run the test?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough. The above test runs fine. But this pretty much the only thing I am capable of testing.  E.g. how would i test res.jsonp(result)?? I  have no idea how to approach that. I'll provide some more explanation. Thanks for the hint

Comment: No prob. Well, you can do it the same way that you have done to check the response status. And also, because the response is `jsonp`. Then, you could try to parse the result with some dummy function to check whether the result is valid or not.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
expressApp.get('', function(req, res, body){
    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
  });
```

you are just mapping the route.

To test your REST API, you have to use a library like [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) (there is an example of testing using express + mocha in that link)

it works this way

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/a_nice_jsonp',cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next){
  var result = parseCookies(req);
  res.jsonp(result);
});

app.get('',function(req,res,next){
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end()
});

describe('app js test', function() {
  describe('GET /', function() {
     it('should respond to GET with empty path', function (done) {
        request(app)
               .get('')
               .expect(200)
               .end(done) 
     });
  });
});
```

**Edited with separated files**

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.get('/a_nice_jsonp',cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next){
  var result = parseCookies(req);
  res.jsonp(result);
});

app.get('',function(req,res,next){
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end()
});
module.exports = app;
```

app-test.js

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('app.js');


describe('app js test', function() {
  describe('GET /', function() {
     it('should respond to GET with empty path', function (done) {
        request(app) 
               .get('')
               .expect(200)
               .end(done) 
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'll look into supertest, what it is and all that. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: One quick question. This may sound a little stupid, but how do I know that the actual file gets tested? At no point do I inject or make use of the app.js file in my test?

Comment: I edited it, now you got both files(app.js/app-test.js). As you can see, app is used inside every request(app).

Comment: Thanks so much. Works perfectly. I think I can handle the rest from here....Thanks again ;)